# How to store a Full html page in to MongoDB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Hi Can any one tell me how can i fetch HTML page and store it in mongoDB, later that i can reference the storied item in ROR(2.3.8).if possible any example is better always to understand .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do a get request to the page you want to save. Then you take the body of the response and save that to MongoDB.

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

res.body   <-  Save this to your MongoDB
```